# Mysql DELETE from table using information from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

So I have these two tables:

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/284ffb2d834ab5aa25ced78fbd30c77c.png))</sub>

The Sites table holds all types of websites to vote on, and Voted_sites table contains all of the sites that been voted on.

Now, sites should get deleted from Voted_sites, when the current date is greater than `date_voted + interval vote_wait_time_hours`.

So in my case I would do it like this:

```
DELETE FROM voted_sites 
LEFT JOIN sites ON voted_sites.site_id = sites.id 
WHERE voted_sites.date_voted < NOW() - INTERVAL sites.vote_wait_time_hours HOUR
```

But unfortunately it gives my syntax error, because I am guessing that you can't use `LEFT JOIN` like that in a delete query.

Basically I need to grab the `vote_wait_time_hours` from `sites` that has the same id key.

Comment: Please provide the error you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `exists` operator with a subquery instead:

```
DELETE 
FROM   voted_sites 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   sites 
               WHERE  voted_sites.site_id = sites.id AND 
                      voted_sites.date_voted < 
                      NOW() - INTERVAL sites.vote_wait_time_hours HOUR);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe in this situation you just need to specify which table you want to delete from, `JOIN` is not the issue.

```
DELETE voted_sites 
FROM voted_sites 
LEFT JOIN sites ON voted_sites.site_id = sites.id 
WHERE voted_sites.date_voted < NOW() - INTERVAL sites.vote_wait_time_hours HOUR
```

Comment: While the accepted answer works, this one answers the question more directly

Answer (score 1):

Change this into a sub-query and it should work.

Here is a rough example (didn't test it):

```
DELETE FROM voted_sites
WHERE voted_sites.date_voted < NOW() - INTERVAL (SELECT vote_wait_time_hours WHERE id = site_id) HOUR
```